# Wind-up toy car constant speed problem

Tags: mechanical, power-transmission, transmission

**Set Up:** In a classic wind-up car we store energy in spring. The energy then used unequaly in time resulting variable speed during the ride. Max torque and power and acceleration at the begining, with a speed peak in the middle and unsufficient torque resulting decceleration at the end and inertia movement at the very end.

For powerfull springs wheels are slipping at the very first seconds wasting energy.

**Problem:**

1. Car shall move at about constant speed all (most of) the ride.
2. I see it as to make a speed(torque? acceleration?) ceiling. At this ceiling the energy from the spring shall be spend ~equal per second. This would obviosly result more prolonged ride (drived ride), with constant speed, and probably variable torque.
3. To make it mechanical

PARTIAL SOLUTIONS ARE WELCOME!!!

**For simplicity:**
The resistance force is constant (no wind, same pavement, no hills on the road)

**I have looked so far:**

1. Clock mechanisms. They do actually solve the very problem but clocks do solve it in discreet movements. Didn't found a way to apply it to the car.
2. Flywheel. Too many drawbacks: prcision, size, gyroscopic effect. And it makes the speed graph flatter, though not so much.
3. CVT. Didn't found simple enough mechanisms that could be scaled down to rasonable toy-size. I assume that scaling down belt and cones will be far to challanging.

Answer (score 0):

So, seen a solution where the spring drove a cone - gives more or less leverage based on the changing force.

Very neat and won the competition.

Comment: Do you have a sketch for that?
Sounds like that moves into the "CVT" direction

Comment: @towe More like a fusee in a wind-up pocket watch. Rather, *exactly* like the fusee of a pocket watch since that was literally why they were invented: to maintain constant force from an unwinding spring.

Comment: @DKNguyen no, actually a cone made around a wooden toothpick (which was the driving axle, as size and mass was limited), cone was made of papier-mache and also had a groove in it to match the reducing tension from the spring. Absolutely smashed the distance record for 5 years - they changed the project as none could get close...

Comment: @SolarMike Well that's what a fusee is isn't it? The cone part driven by a spring.

Answer (score 0):

> "*but clocks do solve it in discreet movements*"

If you think that's a problem then you are missing what it is you really need from the watch. The the balance wheel and pallet fork are responsible for the discrete movements in a watch and they are independent of the *fusee*, and what you need to solve your problem is the fusee.

Not to mention, even if it was discrete, this doesn't matter because electric motors have discrete poles and engines have discrete pistons and they spin wheels just fine.

If you can get a hold of one of those windup car toys, or the toys where you drag the car (like from McDonalds Happy Meals 30 years ago) backwards to wind up the spring through the wheels and then release it to let it go forward, take them apart. They all seem to move a speed that seems too constant to not use a fusee.